# Using Series to Find Limit

Tags: calculus

Could someone please explain, though step by step process on how to use a infinite series to find a limit? Here is the problem that I am stumped on.

> Use the Maclaurin series for $\cos x$ to find 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}{1-\cos x \over x^2}.$$

Comment: do you know the series for $ \cos x $: $$\cos x =1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}-...$$

Comment: yes. I understand how to find the series, but how does that find a limit? That is what I don't understand.

Comment: That is then great, the answer by StackTD (below) explains the procedure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you replace functions by a part of their series representation and the only subtle part is knowing how much of the series you need to use.

I suppose you know that:
$$\cos(x) = 1 - {x^{2} \over 2!} + {x^{4} \over 4!} - \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

If you've heard of the [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), you can use this to express the limiting behavior of the part of the series that you omit. For example, if you keep only the first two terms, you would have:

$$\cos(x) = 1 - {x^{2} \over 2!} + O(x^4) \quad \mbox{for $x \to 0$}$$

Plugging this into the limit, you would get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1- \left( 1 - {x^{2} \over 2!} + O(x^4) \right)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{{x^{2} \over 2!} - O(x^4)}{x^2}$$

Can you simplify and take it from here?

Since you ask, continue like this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{O(x^4)}{x^2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} - \lim_{x \to 0} O(x^2)$$

This last limit is 0 (if that's unclear: look up how Big O works, see previous link).

Comment: I sorry, but could you please continue with your process?

Comment: I added a bit in my answer.